# Cambiar la clase de un boton en una tabla de registros, segun el valor de un campo de la BD

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, bootstrap

Quiero cambiar la clase de un botón dependiendo de lo que traiga el campo "estado" (PENDIENTE O PAGADA) de la BD. Me funciona pero solo toma en cuenta el primer registro. Estoy usando Jquery y php .Les dejo mi código:

```
<?php
require_once ("../clases/Factura.php");


$factura = new Factura();
$datos = $factura->obtenerDatosFactura();



include ("includes/header.php");
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">listado de Facturas</h4>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>N° Documento</th>
                                <th>Fecha Emisión</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>Monto</th>
                                <th>Detalle</th>
                                <th>Estado</th>
                                <th>Rut</th>
                                <th>Razón Social</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datos);$i++){?>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c1"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c2"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c3"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo number_format($datos[$i]['c4'], 0, "", "."); ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c5"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c6"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c8"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <?php echo $datos[$i]["c7"]; ?>
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                    <a href="../procesos/pagarFactura.php?id=<?php echo $datos[$i]["id_factura"]; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" id="btn_pagar" name="btn_pagar" type="submit">Pagar</a>
                                    <a href="editarCuentas.php?id=<?php echo $datos[$i]["id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Editar</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                                    <?php 
                                    $swich=0;
                                    if($datos[$i]["c6"]=="PAGADA"){
                                        $swich = 1;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $swich = 0;
                                    } ?>
                                    <input  type="text" id="swich" value="<?php echo $swich;?>">
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php }?>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#swich").val()==1){
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").removeClass("btn-success");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").addClass("btn-primary");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").text("Pagada");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").addClass("disabled");
    }
    if($("#swich").val()==0){
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").addClass("btn-success");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").removeClass("btn-primary");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").text("Pagar");
        $("[id*=btn_pagar]").removeClass("disabled");
    }
})

</script>

<?php include ("includes/footer.php");?>
```

*Los botones que dicen pagada solo deberian aparecer cuando la columna estado es "PAGADA"*

[image: Los botones que dicen pagada solo deberian aparecer cuando la columna estado es "PAGADA"]

Answer (score 1):

Si no existe interacción trata de hacerlo con CSS.

Creas una clase para Pagada y otra para Pendiente:

```
    .pagada {
color: green;
}

.pendiente {
color: red;
}
```

y montas el input según te interese...

```
<?php 
     $swich=0;
     if($datos[$i]["c6"]=="PAGADA"){
       $swich = 'pagada';
     }
      else{
        $swich = 'pendiente';
       } ?>
       <input  class="<?php echo $swich;?>" type="text" id="swich" value="<?php echo $swich;?>">
```

---

**Con JQuery**

> Uno de los problemas que tiene tu código es que estas usando un id
>   **#** y al salir varios, el JQuery solo actúa  sobre el primero.
>
> Tendrías que utilizar classes **.** y para recorrerlas con un

Por ejemplo

```
<input  type="text" class="swich" value="<?php echo $swich;?>">




  $( ".swich" ).each(function() {

       var status = $(this).val();

       if(status == 'pagada') {
          $( this ).addClass( "pagada" );
       } else if (status == 'pendiente') {
         $( this ).addClass( "pendiente" );
     }

});
```

*Es un ejemplo sin testar pero por aquí van los tiros.*